# File Name not visible in custom file Input control post Partial View Re Rendering via ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

Hope you all are doing well.
I ran into a strange issue. I have an MVC app where I have a Partial view where I have the custom file Input Control. when i first load the page(or whenever reload the full page) I am able to browse file and upload but when I render the partial page via Ajax Call(where the custom file control is) the browse button doesn't display the file name anymore.
If I change the Opacity then I am able to see the filename but that's not the normal behaviour and the native file control is visible as well , which i don't want.
I tried everything but couldn't find the root cause. Requesting the community to check the code and let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

**Custom File input Control**

```
<div class="table-cell width-45percent">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.File, new { @class = "vLabel container-header fileLabel", @for = "File" })
              <div class="control-holder">
               @Html.FileInputControl("File", "TestText", new { @class = "width-75percent", @Name = "File", title = "File", @id = "File" })
              </div>
 </div>
```

**HTML Extension For Custom Control**

```
   public static MvcHtmlString FileInputControl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string labelText, 
      object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            TagBuilder divWrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
            divWrapper.Attributes.Add("class", "fileinputHelper");

            TagBuilder inputTextTag = new TagBuilder("input");
            inputTextTag.Attributes.Add("class", "fileInput_fileName");
            inputTextTag.Attributes.Add("type", "text");
            inputTextTag.Attributes.Add("title", "upload file");

            TagBuilder browseLinkTag = new TagBuilder("div");
            browseLinkTag.Attributes.Add("class", "fileInput_OpenFileDialogButton");
            browseLinkTag.SetInnerText(labelText);

            TagBuilder fakeFileDivWrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
            fakeFileDivWrapper.Attributes.Add("class", "fakefile");
            fakeFileDivWrapper.InnerHtml = inputTextTag.ToString() + browseLinkTag.ToString();

            TagBuilder fileTag = new TagBuilder("input");

            fileTag.Attributes.Add("type", "file");
            fileTag.Attributes.Add("class", "fileInput_file");
            fileTag.Attributes.Add("name", name);
            if (htmlAttributes != null)
                fileTag.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes), replaceExisting: false);

            divWrapper.InnerHtml = fileTag.ToString() + fakeFileDivWrapper.ToString();

            return new MvcHtmlString(divWrapper.ToString());
        }
```

**Javascript Function to handle the File Input**

```
 $(".fileInput_file").change(function () {
        var filePath = $(this).val();
        var fileNameIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
        var filename = filePath.substr(fileNameIndex);
        var inputTextbox = $(".fileInput_fileName", $(this).parent());
        inputTextbox.val(filename);
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
    });
```